# How to install php 5.4.x on ubuntu 13.10 saucy salamander

Tags: 13.10, php

How do I install php 5.4 on ubuntu 13.10 saucy ?

On ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable ( https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5-oldstable ) there are only packages up to 13.04

Please help.

Thank you, Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ppa:ondrej/php5 contains the php5 5.5, you probably meant ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
2. I will add saucy to the list of supported release soon(ish) for ppa:ondrej/php5 (e.g. PHP 5.5)
3. I won't be adding saucy support for ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable (PHP 5.4), if you required PHP 5.4 stick with older release (f.e. precise if you need LTS)

Comment: ad 1.) oh sorry. yes I meant old stable. 2.) thanks , 3.) :-| , for some reason I expteced this. Thanks for your work anyway.

Comment: edited my question and corrected 1.

Answer (score 0):

change repositories to raring  (with backup)

```
sudo sed -i.bak "s/saucy/raring/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

update and install server packages

```
sudo apt-get update
```

add here packages you need and make sure you install php5.4 and apache2.2

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 phpmyadmin
```

change repositories back to saucy

```
sudo sed -i "s/raring/saucy/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

ignore all current upgrades (package hold)

```
sudo apt-mark hold `aptitude -F%p --disable-columns search ~U`
```